# Good books to learn Riemann integration

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, integration, self-learning

I am looking for a good text book to learn Riemann integration. Please suggest books with theories and proofs comprehensively explained.

Comment: Here are a couple of books that contain more than the usual amount on Riemann integration: [**Real Functions, Abstract Spaces and Orthogonal Series**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/9630566524) by Miklos Mikolas; [**Modern Theories of Integration**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0006AWST0) by Hyman Kestelman.

Comment: Apostol's Calculus, Vol 1 is one that I like.

Comment: What is your background? There is a world of difference between Rudin and Spivak, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kenneth Ross' *Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus* has probably the most complete presentation of the Riemann integral you'll find at the beginning level.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you go over Rudin with these notes(section 19):

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-100b-analysis-i-fall-2010/readings-notes/